# Spring MongoDB to update/insert dynamic data using DBObject

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, dynamic

I'm new to MongoDB and I know that with Spring we can have a model class for every collection and do CRUD operations. But is it possible to perform the same without a model class and based on the collection? If I can modify values using `getCollection`, I wont have to worry about what column in modifying.

Something like this,

```
DBCollection dbCollection = mongoTemplate.getCollection(collection);
dbCollection.update("","");
```